# Update UI after screenLock

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, start-activity

I am in the A Activity and  i B activity in the BrodcastReceiver.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            //start activity

            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, Pause.class);
                    i.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                      | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                      | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

              context.startActivity(i);

                  }
                });

            wasScreenOn = false;

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when unlocking the screen the activity A appears for a second before displaying the activity B. How can I fix?

Comment: is there any code in Activity B that takes extra time before getting it ready?

Comment: is an Activity with simple FrameLayout and a static textView.

Comment: hmmm shouldn't be an issue then. As an advice: dont give STATIC to you TextView, it may cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Code looks good. This is not a problem with your application, Android on Screen Unlock has a similar behaviour with other apps as well. Probably this might also be as system may suspend the startActivity to after it has woken up from low power state. So you may want to revisit when you update the UI, during screen off or after screen on.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is indifferent where I put the code for the startActivity() in the Receiver.

Comment: Usually in onRecieve() the system takes a wake lock, so there is some delay there, then to launch a new activity, UI needs to be invalidated, and entire view has to be redrwan, hence the lag. Waqas has some good suggestions, try them!

Answer (score 0):

If the delay is due to transition from one activity to another with animation then you may simply set the following flag to your intent which disables animation, making your activity to be visible quickly.

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
```

In case, it still doesn't solve the delay, then try to put the code of your activity B that might be taking time in processing (like database calls) inside an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: what do you mean for the code of your activity B? The code to startActivity B?